# Setting the visibility property on a button to true is doing nothing

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Here is a snippet of the code that I am working with: (`btnEditTop` is a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button`)

```
if( userCanEdit )
{
     this.btnEditTop.Visible = true;
}
```

When I'm stepping through the code with the debugger.  At the start of the `if` statement, in the watch window, the value of `Visible` is false.  As I step into the `if`, and after the `= true` statement, the value of `Visible` is still false.

This code is in a function that does work it some situations, but not in one case.

There must be something that I am doing that prevents `Visible` from being set.

Does anyone know what conditions will cause this?

Comment: Is it within a container that's also invisible, a div perhaps or a Panel?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness - would the button actually inherit the value of its own visible property from the parent control?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness you're a genius!  That is exactly it.

Comment: @mlsteeves. You flatter me. I've hit that so many times it's a knee-jerk reaction ;)

Comment: @tomasmcguinness  :)  If you want to put an answer to the question, I'd happily accept it and give you an upvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it within a container that's also invisible, a div perhaps or a Panel?